# Repeater и DataBind()

Tags: asp.net, xml, .net

Задача:
сортировка в Repeater, который берет данные из XmlDataSource.
сортировка (код внутри репитера)

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SortNameButton" CommandName="sortByName" runat="server">Наименование</asp:LinkButton>
          </td>
          <td>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="SortPriceButton" CommandName="sortByPrice" runat="server">Цена</asp:LinkButton>
          </td>
          <td>
```

событие обрабатываю в

```
protected void RepeaterItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "delete":
                {
                    ..
                    break;
                }
            case "edit":
                {
                   ..
                    break;
                }
            case "sortByName":
                {
                    ...
                    break;
                }
            case "sortByPrice":
                {
                    ...
                    break;
                }
              }
           Repeater.DataBind();
```

допустим в sortByName сортирует по имени и сохраняет в xml.
подебажил, все работает верно. но когда запустил при клике на ссылку

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SortNameButton" CommandName="sortByName" runat="server">Наименование</asp:LinkButton>
```

или

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SortPriceButton" CommandName="sortByPrice" runat="server">Цена</asp:LinkButton>
```

xml отсортирован и сохранен, а в репитере это появиться через несколько таких операций , в чем загвоздка ?

Comment: в смысле что DataBind() не хочет так часто обновляться, из кеша? попробовать перед DataBind() удалить кеш у репитера?

Comment: сделал HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(моя страница) не помогло

Comment: обновляться четко при втором клике по ссылке, с при первом не хочет при этом страница перегружается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отключил кеш у xmldatasourse, и вуаля все работает